# Saving GridSplitter position

Tags: wpf

I have this:

```
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <GridSplitter Background="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrush}"
          Grid.Column="1"
          Margin="0,0,0,0"
          Name="splitter"
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
```

I'm trying to save and restore the splitter position. I'm using `grid.ColumnDefinitions[0].Width`, which returns the width of the column in pixels.

When I restore the position, how do I restore AND keep the 50* setting, so that when you resize the window, the column resizes correctly?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The **Width** property is not a simple `double`, it is a `System.Windows.GridLength` object which contains the **Value** property (`double`) and a **GridUnitType** property (`GridUnitType`) which is an `enum`.
So, to set your column's width to 50*:

```
grid.ColumnDefinitions[0].Width = new GridLength(50, GridUnitType.Star)
```

To save and restore all you need to do is to save the value and the `GridUnitType` for each column.

Hope it helps.

Comment: My question is why is the width value comprised of a double? It makes serialization even more difficult due to rounding errors.

Comment: If you want also to save the value I would suggest using GridUnitType.Pixel so you do not have to convert anything